# overscroll-behavior works only when a mouse event is triggered

Tags: javascript, css

According to MDN docs about [over-scrolling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overscroll-behavior):

While scrolling a child element inside a parent, the parent element will scroll when the scrolling boundary of the child element is reached. However, this only happens when a mouse event is triggered.

For example, we scroll until we reach the end of the child element. The scrolling stops and only continues scrolling the parent element if a mouse click or movement is detected.

How can I have a smooth continuous overscrolling behavior without the need to move the mouse?

Comment: From the link you posted, it says possible values are `contain` and `none`, but in both cases it says «No scroll chaining occurs to neighboring scrolling, e.g. underlying elements will not scroll.» I think this is mostly used to prevent the "bouncing" effect you see when overscrolling elements on mobile browsers

Comment: Hi, I am experiencing the same. Have you found a work around yet?

Comment: @teebo No(fixed that by negotiation with the customer). But I think you can add an event listener to the scrollable element and fire a mouse event whenever the boundary is reached.